# Reading edited cells from three QtableWidgets

Tags: python, pyqt5

In each of the three tables the 'edit' column is the only one that can be edited by the user. My problem is that I can't know in which table the edit was done as all three are "generated" by the same call

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem

```
class NewBook(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 60, 700, 250))
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle("Aggiornamento Titoli")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        title = 'aaa'
        x = 20
        y = 30
        x1 = 210
        y1 = 152
        aaatot = self.build_table(title, x, y, x1, y1)
        x = 250
        y = 30
        x1 = 210
        y1 = 152
        title = 'bbb'
        bbbtot = self.build_table(title, x, y, x1, y1)
        x = 480
        y = 30
        x1 = 210
        y1 = 152
        title = 'ccc'
        ccctot = self.build_table(title, x, y, x1, y1)
        self.upd_Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.upd_Button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 200, 81, 20))
        self.upd_Button.setObjectName("upd_Button")

        self.upd_Button.setText("upd")
        self.upd_Button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.show()

    def build_table(self, title, x, y, x1, y1):

        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.table.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(x, y, x1, y1))
        self.table.setColumnCount(5)
        self.table.setRowCount(0)
        self.table.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(False)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().hide()
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(10)
        self.table.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(25)


        t_row = 0
        i = 0
        ttl_array = ['a','b','c','edit','e']
        self.table.insertRow(t_row)
        while i <= 4:
            item = ttl_array[i]
            cell = QTableWidgetItem(item)
            self.table.setItem(t_row, i, cell)
            i += 1
        tot = 0
        t_row += 1
        while t_row <= 5:
            self.table.insertRow(t_row)
            cell = QTableWidgetItem('phone')
            self.table.setItem(t_row, 0, cell)

            cell = QTableWidgetItem('fax')
            self.table.setItem(t_row, 1, cell)

            cell = QTableWidgetItem('available')
            self.table.setItem(t_row, 2, cell)

            cell = QTableWidgetItem(' ')
            self.table.setItem(t_row, 3, cell)

            cell = QTableWidgetItem('busy')
            self.table.setItem(t_row, 4, cell)
            t_row += 1

        return tot

    def on_click(self):
        pass

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = NewBook()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Where are you getting that a table has been edited? There's nothing in your code that does that. Also, every time you call `build_table` you're overwriting the previous `self.table`, so you're losing its reference. Besides, you should not try to mimic or edit a pyuic generated file (read more about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html)), and you should also use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).

Comment: With `'designer` I tried to build a layout with 3 tables inside. Three separate tables are created which assumes a code for each table which is just what I don't want.
I solved the problem by naming each table before calling the processing code. In this way only the three containers are created, the processing code remains unique and I can easily read what interests me `aaatable =  QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        aaatot= self.build_table(aaatable, title, x, y, x1, y1)` and   ` def build_table(self, table, title, x, y, x1, y1):
        ...`